# How to graph 3 different lines in the same graph with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I want to draw 3 line graphs on the same graph (to compare the data).  They share the same x axis, and use the same data for the y axis but with different values.  How can I do this?  It's not working out well for me.

What I tried:

Highlight data from first line graph.  Insert -> 2D line graph.  Right click on graph, select data.  From here on out it's just not making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a three line comparison graph by selecting all of the data as a block i.e. the X axis and the three Y axis data points. I then used the same Insert > Line > 2D line.

The chart popped up as desired.

I don't know if it made a difference but I had the data arranged in columns with headings, i.e.

```
Column A - X axis
Column B - Data set 1
Column C - Data set 2
Column D - Data set 3
```

Comment: put data set labels in row 1, and keep cell A1 blank, to help Excel parse the data into X and Y values.